# How to close a SplFileObject file handler?

Tags: php, spl

I'm working with files in PHP using SplFileInfo and SplFileObject.
But when I try to "re-open" a file, it yells me :

```
 SplFileObject::__construct(filemame): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I think I should close my file before re-opening it, but I can't figures how. 
`SplFile*` have no `close` function ?!

Comment: I don't think you opened the file, it's ` Permission denied`. Simply  the permission problem.

Comment: Set `SplFileObject` to `null` as said here: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.splfileobject.php#113149

Comment: I'm on Windows... I don't think there are permissions problems. Also, the first time I'm opening and writing in this files, that works...

Comment: But be careful, that in case you have multiple variables pointing to the same `SplFileObject` you must be sure to set ALL of them to `null` so that your object is destroyed (and garbage collected). More on destroying of objects http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/11/14/php-dont-call-the-destructor-explicitly/

Answer (score 23):

You should set [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/manual/tr/class.splfileobject.php) to `null` in order to close the file.

```
<?php

     $fileHandler = new SplFileObject('file.name');
     //now file.name is open

     $fileHandler = null;
     //file.name is closed.

     $fileHandler2 = new SplFileObject('file.name');
     //file.name is re-opened

?>
```

Comment: So essentially, it closes on `__destruct`?

Comment: so `unset` gives the same effect?